# VBA SQL missing last condition of WHERE clause

Tags: sql, vba, ado

I have pulled the last of what little hair I have left out trying to get what I thought was a fairly simple SQL statement to run through VBA. When the string for the statement compiles, it is cutting off the last condition of the WHERE clause and I can't work out how to fix it. Please help!

My SQL string looks like this:

```
sSQL = "UPDATE Allocations SET WithdrawalDate =" & dThisWithdrawDate & ",Notes = '" & sNotes & "' WHERE StaffID =" & lID & " AND PatientID = " & lThisPatientID & ";"
```

The string compiles with the StaffID variable and cuts off the AND part of the clause. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to get into the habit of using parameters. SQL concatenation is dangerous.

Comment: Once I get it working, I may try and refactor it using parameters. It is for very restricted (local) use, so risks are pretty low. Thanks for the advice :)

Comment: Because you're using string concatenation, it's possible that something in your sNotes string (an apostrophe, or perhaps a carriage return?) is terminating the SQL statement early in some way. Show us the *exact* value of sSQL if you want to diagnose the problem, or try again using proper parameters and see if the problem goes away. And bear in mind it's not just about security. If your notes have the word "don't" in them (that apostrophe is a single quote character), for example, your statement will not work, as the `'` will close the open quote of `Notes = ...'`

Comment: Matt, I think you have solved this for me. There was an apostrophe in my notes string. I have supplied a notes string without punctuation and it parsed the SQL statement as I needed it to be, Thanks!

Comment: @MattGibson  Good point - have updated my answer so that notes has a ' in it.

Comment: @MattGibson I'm going to mark Darren Bartrup-Cook's solution as the answer, but your comment is the one that made me understand what I had done wrong,so thanks for that again.

Comment: Fine by me, and you're welcome.

Comment: @MrCholmondleyWarner  lol, first time I've looked at your user name ... took a while to sink in who it is. :)

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook :) An oldie, but a jolly good show.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another way, as @Kostas suggested is to use parameters:

```vb
Sub Test()

    Dim dThisWithdrawDate As Date
    Dim sNotes As String
    Dim lID As Long
    Dim lThisPatientID As Long

    dThisWithdrawDate = DateSerial(2018, 6, 10)
    sNotes = "This note's not possible without hassle in string concat."
    lID = 1
    lThisPatientID = 2

    With CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", _
        "Parameters WithdrawDate DateTime, PatientNotes Text(255), " & _
        "StaffIdentifier Long, PatientIdentifier Long; " & _
        "UPDATE Allocations SET WithdrawalDate = WithDrawDate, Notes = PatientNotes " & _
        "WHERE StaffID = StaffIdentifier AND PatientID = PatientIdentifier")

        .Parameters("WithdrawDate") = dThisWithdrawDate
        .Parameters("PatientNotes") = sNotes
        .Parameters("StaffIdentifier") = lID
        .Parameters("PatientIdentifier") = lThisPatientID
        .Execute

    End With

End Sub
```

Or you can use something like:  `With db.QueryDefs("DML_Update_AllocationTable")` if using a stored query.

Comment: Thanks Darren, I was going to look at how to do it with parameters later anyway, this looks like a far better way to do what I am trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do it somehow replicable:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim sSql As String
    Dim dThisWithdrawDate As String: dThisWithdrawDate = "foo"
    Dim sNotes As String: sNotes = "bar"
    Dim lID As Long: lID = 5
    Dim lThisPatientID As Long: lThisPatientID = 10

    sSql = "UPDATE Allocations SET WithdrawalDate =" & dThisWithdrawDate & ",Notes = '" & sNotes & "' WHERE StaffID =" & lID & " AND PatientID = " & lThisPatientID & ";"
    Debug.Print sSql

End Sub
```

The code above prints:

```
UPDATE Allocations SET WithdrawalDate =foo,Notes = 'bar' WHERE StaffID =5 AND PatientID = 10;
```

Thus, the AND clause is cut off from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks Vityata. This is very odd, as I have added a break and a watch on the string sSQL, which is a straightforward assignment as above, and immediately after the assignment the string value is: 
"UPDATE [Allocations] SET WithdrawalDate =22/06/2018,Notes = 'some text' WHERE StaffID =10 
                     - which is missing PatientID

Comment: @MrCholmondleyWarner Is that valid SQL? On most databases, I'd expect the date value to need quotes.

Comment: I hadn't got that far Matt, it probably isn't valid. I just concatenated a date variable to add it to the string, so it is whatever VBA generated. Sounds like I'll need to wrap it in quotes... I'll now know why it doesn't run :D